# DevExtreme Angular 5

Tags: angular, angular-pipe, devextreme-angular

I'm using DevExtreme for Angular 5 i usually use my pipe (filtre) like this

```
[label]="{text: 'CompanyPage.Category'|translate}"
```

but i dont know how to use the pipe with caption

```
  <dxi-item itemType="group" [items]="[]"  caption="Complement|translate" cssClass="block1" [colCount]="7">
```

translate here is not detected as a filtre but its detected as a string
 is there anyway to use pipe there without changing the caption option ? 
Thanks for helping.

Comment: `[caption]="'Complement'|translate"`

Comment: @yurzui thanks , its working .